# What is the exact meaning of 'in the first approximation' in the context of applied mathematics?

Tags: approximation, approximation-theory

In the applied mathematics textbooks or papers, I often see the phrase 'in the first approximation'. For example, substitution of Eq.(1) into the boundary condition (2) results in Eq.(3) describing ... *in the first approximation*.

Comment: You can see the Wiki page on Order of Approximation.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on context, this can vary from a very formal usage to a very informal one.  Commonly, this means "to one term of the Taylor series expansion", but it can also mean one term or one iteration of whatever expansion/recursive method is relevant. Less formally, it tends to mean the crudest approximation that the speaker believes has credibility and utility.  Informally, it can mean a naïve approximation, or one using a "quick and dirty" methods, without regard to exactly where that fits into any series of approximations.  At a similar level of informality, "second approximation" may indicate that the speaker has taken some care to refine the estimate, but greater care is probably needed for firm conclusions.